# Solving the Jump function in discontinuous Galerkin method

Tags: finite-element, numerical-analysis, discontinuous-galerkin

I am trying to solve the elasticity equation using Crouzeix-Raviart element. Since this can not be solved using continuous FEM I am trying to solve this by discontinuous Galerkin method. In the discontinuous Galerkin formulation the left hand part of equation $a(U,v)$ term has two parts, the first part is the stiffness and the second part provides the stabilization to the equation.

The stabilization term has the jump function $\int[U][v] $, where $[U]=U^+-U^- $ and $[v]=v^+-v^- $. I am finding it difficult to implement this. Could someone please suggest some literature which explains how the jump term is treated in matrix form and is solved.

Comment: Step 12 of the `deal.II` tutorial gives a good example of how to implement the DG jump terms. Their equation is simpler (advection) and they use the standard DG-FEM discontinuous polynomial basis, but it is (imo) a good starting point. Here is the [link](https://www.dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_12.html)

Comment: To see how this is done, I would suggest to expand the functions with respect to the local bases of the neighboring elements. In this way you can see how to assemble the corresponding blocks that introduce the coupling in the stiffness matrix.